# Problemas con Foreach en C#

Tags: c#

Buen día a todos, hoy programando algo pequeño me he encontrado con algo extraño que no me había pasado antes, al realizar un *foreach* para que me recorra la una cadena de texto pero me encuentro que esta estructura.

La estructura me indica que *var* es de tipo *char* y no es *string* como debiese ser, ¿A que se debe esto? nunca me había pasado, cabe mencionar que al realizar `item.contains` no me deja realizarlo porque reconoce ítem como tipo *char*.

```
texto = File.ReadAllText(destino);
foreach (var item in texto)
{
    if (item.Contains(""))
    {
        // Aqui va el codigo....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero, vamos a fijarnos en la firma del método [ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0):

```
public static string ReadAllText (string path);
```

Como vemos, este método devuelve una variable de tipo `string`. Cuando tienes un `string` y le aplicas un `foreach`, obviamente el resultado es cada uno de los `char` que contiene el `string`.

Supongo que lo querías usar es [`ReadAllLines`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0), que como vemos:

```
public static string[] ReadAllLines (string path);
```

devuelve un array de `string`, y ahi si que un `foreach` devolverá cada una de las lineas.